# Zend Framework 2 - Annotation form - Bind doesn't work

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-form, zend-framework2

I'm using `AnnotationForms` and I altered my standard edit action from the tutorial to use Annotation and not standard forms.

Everything works except the `$form->bind()` doesn't fill in the values. The form fields stay empty.

I checked my variable which should be binded and it is set and looks good.

Here's my action:

```
    $id = (int)$this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('id');
    if (!$id) {
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('album', array('action'=>'add'));
    }
    $album = $this->getEntityManager()->find('Album\Entity\Album', $id);

    $builder = new AnnotationBuilder();
    $form    = $builder->createForm(new \Album\Entity\Album());
    $form->add(new \MyVendor\Form\MyFieldset());
    $form->setBindOnValidate(false);
    $form->bind($album);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, this was an easy one!

The trick is to transform your object to an array and use `setData()` instead of bind.

I found the solution hint [here](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.form.quick-start.html#validating-forms).

You still need `bind()` for saving the changes. If you leave it out, no error occurs but it won't save it either.

```
 $album = $this->getEntityManager()->find('Album\Entity\Album', $id);
 ...
 $form->bind($album);
 $form->setData($album->getArrayCopy());
```

Answer (score 2):

The `ClassMethods` hydrator does actually work on bind, but the form element names need to match the lower-case-underscore Format (example: object property `$moduleDisplayName`, `ClassMethods` and `ObjectProperty` hydrator expect form element Name `module_display_name`.

The `Zend\Form\Annotation` by default produces a form element named `moduleDisplayName`. Therefore extracting the object to the form does not work.

Solution 1: Add the `@Name` Annotation to the property for `ClassMethods` to work.

Example:

```
/**
* @Form\Name("module_display_name")
protected $moduleDisplayName
```

Solution 2: Instantiate the `ClassMethods` hydrator with the optional Parameter `underScoreSeperatedKeys` set to `false` (Default is `true`) or use `ClassMethods::setUnderScoreSeperatedKeys(false)`. Then `ClassMethods` will behave like any other hydrator.

The `ObjectProperty` hydrator works only on properties declared `public`. But naming is the same as with `ArraySerializable` (i.e. property `$moduleDisplayName`, form element Name `moduleDisplayName`).

The `Reflection` hydrator works on all properties. Naming is the same as with `ArraySerializable`.

Conclusion: `ClassMethods` is the one of four hydrators which expects a different form element naming scheme. Not too cool.